# formula for reward points in opencart 2.2.0.0?

Tags: opencart

I need to change the value of reward point, ex. 1 point = Rs 1, then how can I change 1$ price value in opencart.

I am using opencart for implementing my ecomm website. I have added reward feature in it. I want that if user has 500 points then it can be equivalent to Rs 500. But at present it is equal to Rs. 136. Can any one help me out on the same.

Thank you

Comment: Does your site support both currency or only Rs currency?

Comment: No, Only Rupees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using only one currency so if you add the same Points at the Reward Points while adding the products then it will work.

[image: Opencart Reward]

As per your example:
Rs 1 == 1points
Then when you add the products go to Reward Points tab and add the same points as the cost of products.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Reward Points Tab**

Reward points is a feature of OpenCart that assigns customers "loyalty points" for purchasing products from the store. Customers can use these acquired points as a currency to purchase products from the store. You can assign this product a certain number of reward points required for a customer to purchase it with. If you don't want to allow this product to be bought with reward points, you can simply leave this area blank.

[image]

Thanks